# Unrecognized selector sent to class (singleton)

Tags: ios, swift3, state-restoration

I have found a few related topics on this question, but I don't understand how the solutions presented there are applicable to a singleton class.

When my app starts up, I call `gamestate.shardInstance()` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` but it immediately crashes with the same error every time:

`2017-03-22 11:09:09.102 project-mars[46108:28079112] +[project_mars.gameState encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103670e60
2017-03-22 11:09:09.107 project-mars[46108:28079112] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[project_mars.gameState encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103670e60'`

Can someone please help me understand what exactly is happening in this error and how to fix it? Thank you!

```
class gameState: NSObject, NSCoding {

var GameSettings:gameSettings   //Structure that stores all the game settings
var PlayerStats:gameStatistics     //Structure that stores all game stats
var GameBoard:gameBoard        //Contains the information of the gameboard

private static var Instance: gameState = {
    let instance = gameState.loadgameState()
    //Closure for configuration
    return instance!
}()

private override init(){
    self.GameSettings = gameSettings()
    self.PlayerStats = gameStatistics()
    self.GameBoard = gameBoard()
    super.init()
}

class func sharedInstance() -> gameState{
    return gameState.Instance
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.GameSettings = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "GameSettings") as? gameSettings)!
    self.PlayerStats = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "PlayerStats") as? gameStatistics)!
    self.GameBoard = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "GameBoard") as? gameBoard)!
}
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(gameState.sharedInstance().GameSettings, forKey: "GameSettings")
    aCoder.encode(gameState.sharedInstance().PlayerStats, forKey: "PlayerStats")
    aCoder.encode(gameState.sharedInstance().GameBoard, forKey: "GameBoard")
}
class func loadgameState() ->gameState? {
    let path = gameState.getFilePath()
    print("PATH: \(path) \n")
    if gameState.fileExistsAtPath(path: path){
        if let rawData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
            /// do we get serialized data back from the attempted path?
            /// if so, unarchive it into an AnyObject, and then convert to a GameData object
            if(rawData.length != 0){
                if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: rawData as Data) as? gameState {
                    return data
                }
            }
        }
        return gameState()
    }else{
        return gameState()
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense but your code is horrible to read. The naming convention (upper and lowercase) is the other way round.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'd say thats a stylistic preference, but to each their own. If you can't read it don't, I don't think its very unclear.

Comment: When your stylistic preference is the exact opposite of the frameworks you are interfacing with and also makes the SO syntax highlighter make everything the wrong color then it makes your code hard to read.

Comment: Where is the `gameState.loadgameState()` method?  As everyone else has already mentioned - its typical that this static method should be named `GameState.loadGameState()`.  Also, you should look into a more Swifty singleton pattern `static let sharedInstance = gameState()` is all you need

Comment: I agree with Vadian, that code is very confusing to read. I was looking at calls to static methods and instinctively thought they were instance methods which do a very different thing.

Comment: It looks like there is something missing from the code too, where is the `loadgameState()` method?

Comment: Thanks I added the `loadgameState()` method. I haven't found any useful guides on swift singletons so I've kinda pieced it together from ObjC code I found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the local instance, without calling out to the singleton here.  You're already in the singleton instance

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(gameState.GameSettings, forKey: "GameSettings")
    aCoder.encode(gameState.PlayerStats, forKey: "PlayerStats")
    aCoder.encode(gameState.GameBoard, forKey: "GameBoard")
}
```

Please share the `gameState.loadgameState()` static method - my guess is something else is happening there.